# Move all AD users from one OU to another

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need some assistance as I am stuck trying to write a simple PS script that will roll users to the next OU.

For an example, I would like to move all accounts from `test1` to `test2`:

```
$ou1 = 'OU=test1,OU=users,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$ou2 = 'OU=test 2,OU=users,DC=contoso,DC=local'

$adUserGroup = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} -SearchBase ($ou1) -Properties $properties | Select-object $properties | Sort-Object samAccountName

foreach($user in $adUserGroup)
    {
    "Moving Active Directory user $($user.Name)"
    move-adobject -Identity "$user" -targetpath $ou2
    }
```

Comment: What about your code isn't working? Any error messages?

Comment: you better add the error message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define `$properties` anywhere, so `Select-Object` isn't actually doing anything. It can be removed as it's not really needed for this task as the default properties are fine.

`Sort-Object` is also not required unless you really care that the users are moved in alphabetical order of their username..

I would also change `Filter` as it doesn't need a scriptblock `{ }` -- it can just be quoted `' '`

```
$ou1 = 'OU=test1,OU=users,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$ou2 = 'OU=test 2,OU=users,DC=contoso,DC=local'

$AdUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq "True"' -SearchBase $ou1

foreach($user in $AdUsers) {
    Write-Output "Moving Active Directory user: $($user.Name)"
    Move-ADObject -Identity $user -TargetPath $ou2
}
```

You can actually use the pipeline to make the process a single command, using `-Verbose` to provide output about which user it's moving:

```
$ou1 = 'OU=test1,OU=users,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$ou2 = 'OU=test 2,OU=users,DC=contoso,DC=local'

Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq "True"' -SearchBase $ou1 | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $ou2 -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a single line by not using variables

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq "True"' -SearchBase 'OU=test1,DC=contoso,DC=com' | Move-ADObject -TargetPath 'OU=Test2,DC=contoso,DC=com' -Verbose
```

Comment: It's not always good to fit everything in one line. Especially when working in a team, readability is more important than efficiency of the code.